# How to store audios, videos and other files in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a database for my files so that I can search easily without the help of "windows search".

Is it possible to store audio, video and other files in MySQL database in the tables?

Comment: Not the way to do things. Store them in a filesysyem & store their metadata in the database

Comment: why not just store the file path and the meta-data about the files?  It is generally considered a bad idea to store BLOBS in the database.

Comment: Can you plz tell me the procedure for that?